# How to execute or run .sql file inside stored procedure in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, job-scheduling

I am trying to create stored procedure to create scheduled task . Which will execute my .sql script daily. My .sql file contains create table and drop table scripts. like this

```
Drop table a608232_new_62K_master;

create table a608232_new_62K_master as select A.* from 
a608232_MRD_DATA_62K_W_Account A inner join a608232_new_mids B
on A.MID = B.MID;
```

Many more statements like this which updates that table daily. How should I proceed regarding this. I am trying to create procedure so that i can schedule a task to execute that procedure. Or is there some other way to this in oracle.

ps: I have only 1 .sql file which contains all the statements.

Comment: Have you considered Scheduling Jobs with Oracle Scheduler?

Comment: @TedatORCL.Pro yeah but i didnt know how to execute .sql file using that?

Comment: why you want to keep your scripts in files? any reason for that at all? could they be pl/sql blocks?

Comment: @TedatORCL.Pro Yeah they can be PL/SQL blocks. I havent done this before. So not familiar with syntax. If i keep them in PL/SQL block how should i proceed

Comment: BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
   job_name           =>  'update_sales',
   job_type           =>  'STORED_PROCEDURE',
   job_action         =>  'OPS.SALES_PKG.UPDATE_SALES_SUMMARY',
   start_date         =>  '28-APR-08 07.00.00 PM Australia/Sydney',
   repeat_interval    =>  'FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=2', /* every other day */
   end_date           =>  '20-NOV-08 07.00.00 PM Australia/Sydney',
   auto_drop          =>   FALSE,
   job_class          =>  'batch_update_jobs',
   comments           =>  'My new job');
END;
/

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/scheduse.htm#ADMIN034

Comment: @TedatORCL.Pro I saw this the part i didnt figure out is where should i Put my SQL statements. The drop table and create table statements.

Comment: put the in proc within a package and use execute immediate where required for DDL, makes sense?

Comment: yeah Thanks. Will try to do that

Comment: My pleasure, let me know if you need further assistance

Comment: Why not use the OS scheduler, and submit the .sql file to the sql*plus in a shell script? It's cleaner this way.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using Oracle Scheduler to execute your scripts with PL/SQL Packages Procs and use execute immediate when required for DDL.

Hope that works out for you.

Regards,

Ted

Comment: I found one way is to use execute immidiate but it is giving me problems when i have statement like this `create table abd as select * from xyz where a='b'`. I have to use single quotes after execute immidiate but those getting mixed up with 'b'

Comment: Use a = '''b'''

Comment: Thanks for my proc is created but facing an issue while creating table. The first statement is getting executed i can drop the table but cant create it. It says insufficient privledges

Comment: I am doing this becoz i want to schedule a job that will run this proc daily to refresh data in table.

Comment: Then you need to grand appropriate privileges to the schema/user that the proc lives in.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the code in your `.sql` file, inside a stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myproc

AS

BEGIN

Drop table a608232_new_62K_master;

create table a608232_new_62K_master as select A.* from 
a608232_MRD_DATA_62K_W_Account A inner join a608232_new_mids B
on A.MID = B.MID;` 

END
```

Then You can automate this using a batch file and windows task scheduler.

```
set MYDB= yourDBname
set MYUSER=youruser 
set MYPASSWORD=yourpassword 
set MYSERVER=yourservername 
sqlcmd -S %MYSERVER% -d %MYDB% -U %MYUSER% -P %MYPASSWORD% -h -1 -s "," -W -Q "exec myproc"
```

Comment: well if you put DDL statements in stored procedure like this it throws error. How to tackle that

Comment: I found one way is to use execute immidiate but it is giving me problems when i have statement like this `create table abd as select * from xyz where a='b'`. I have to use single quotes after execute immidiate but those getting mixed up with 'b'

Comment: did you try the query i posted as the new answer, did it work?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a table like this :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myproc

AS

BEGIN

Drop table a608232_new_62K_master;

create table a608232_new_62K_master (col1, col2, col3...) -- Note: Its better to name the columns in the table, same as the columns used by the select query

insert into a608232_new_62K_master (col1, col2, col3...)
select A.col1, A.col2, A.col3 from 
a608232_MRD_DATA_62K_W_Account A 
inner join a608232_new_mids B
on A.MID = B.MID;` 

END
```